# How similar is using a secondary index in InnoDB to using a second table joining 'into' the PK?

Tags: index, innodb, join

Since InnoDB secondary indexes are separate B-trees with the key as the sort order and the PK as the 'value' stored, I assumed that reading into the main table by the secondary index was a lot like certain joining scenarios, but this seems not to be true for performance at least.

Here's an example

```
CREATE TABLE abc (a int unsigned, b int unsigned, c int unsigned, PRIMARY KEY (a), UNIQUE KEY (b));
```

`a` is the (ordered) set of numbers from 0 to 1000000. b is the "randomly" ordered set of the same numbers.  So they're not parallel.

The following is intended to be an imitation of the secondary index `b` on `abc`.

```
CREATE TABLE ba (b int unsigned, a int unsigned, PRIMARY KEY (b));

INSERT INTO ba SELECT b, a FROM abc ORDER BY b ASC;
```

In the following examples I will SELECT `c` so as to prevent `Using Index`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT AVG(c) FROM  abc WHERE b > 702991 AND b < 900000;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | abc   | range | b             | b    | 4       | NULL | 385202 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT AVG(c) FROM ba JOIN abc USING (a) WHERE ba.b > 702991 AND ba.b < 900000;

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ba    | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL      | 403560 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | abc   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | perf.ba.a |      1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

I wasn't expecting the explains to be identical  But, for example, why can't we use MRR in the latter query?  Why can't we buffer the `a`s we read in off `ba`, sort those, and then do a range query into `abc`? It's at least *relationally* equivalent to the former query.

As expected, both queries yield the exact same result.  However, the secondary index one takes about 1 second and then join one takes about 10 seconds, with default mysql settings.

Can someone explain why that is?

Thanks